# Saving HABTM models to mutiple databases in cakePHP not working correctly

Tags: cakephp

```
function save($data = null, $validate = true, $fieldList = array()) {
$this->setDataSource('master');
$isSave = parent::save($data, $validate, $fieldList);
$this->setDataSource('default');
    $isSave = parent::save($data, $validate, $fieldList);
    return $isSave;
}
```

In my AppModel I am attempting to duplicate saves into two databases. However, I'm finding the HABTM parts of the data to save is only being saved to the 'default' datasource. I'm assuming that the associations are attached by an event listener perhaps? Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might also have this problem caused by line 1789 of Model.php $dbMulti = $this->{$withModel}->getDataSource(); it switches your datasource back to default.